# Difficulty with Definition of Disconnectedness w.r.t. closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, definition, connectedness

Here's what I know:
*When is a (metric) space disconnected?*

> Consider a metric space $(M,d)$. $M$ is disconnected if there exist non-empty disjoint open subsets $A,B \subset M$ such that $A\cup B = M$. $\{A,B\}$ is called a disconnection of $M$.

*When is a subset of $M$ disconnected?*$\color{red}{^1}$

> Consider $E\subset M$. $E$ is disconnected if there exists non-empty disjoint open subsets $A,B \subset M$ such that $E\subset A\cup B$, $A\cap E\neq \varnothing$ and $B\cap E\neq \varnothing$.

I have seen that using the first definition, people often say that $M$ is disconnected if there exist non-empty disjoint **closed sets** such that $A\cup B = M$. This makes sense here, since $A^c = B$ and $B^c = A$, so if $A,B$ are open, they are *also closed.*

What about the second definition though, i.e. when is $E$ disconnected? **Can we come up with something in terms of closed sets here?**

My problem is that in the second definition, $A^c$ is not necessarily $B$ - so nothing useful comes out of that apparently. Could someone help me out here, and better clarify notions of connectedness/disconnectedness for me? Thank you very much.

---

**Footnote:**
$\color{red}{1.}$ In Carothers' Real Analysis, this characterization of disconnectedness of subsets of $M$ has been motivated by the *relative metric*, and notions of open sets in $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset $E \subseteq M$ is disconnected exactly when $(E,d)$ in the relative metric (or as a topologist would say, the subspace topology) is disconnected.

We can also use the same reformulation as you have given but with closed sets instead.
So

> $E$ is disconnected if there exists non-empty disjoint **closed** subsets $A,B \subset M$ such that $E\subset A\cup B$, $A\cap E\neq \varnothing$ and $B\cap E\neq \varnothing$.

The reason that this works is that $A \cap E$ and $B \cap E$ are then open and closed in $(E,d)$ just as in the open $A$,$B$ case.

Sidenote: for general (non-metric) spaces we don't demand that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ but $A \cap B \cap E = \emptyset$, to avoid weird examples). So the sets need only be disjoint **on $E$**, not in the whole space.

Comment: How can I prove that the reformulation with closed sets is actually true? In the case of the first definition, the proof is easy. In case of this (second), is there a nice way to reformulate it using the *open sets* version?

Comment: $A \cap E$ and $B \cap E$ are each other's complement in $E$. So in the open case, they are  both open and closed in $(E,d)$ and in the closed case the same holds, entirely symmetrically... @strawberry-sunshine

Comment: Well just to confirm: Suppose $E\subset M$, and $A$ is open in $E$. That already means that $A\subset E$, right? Also, the complement of $A$ in $E$ should be $E\setminus A$ - that would be closed right?

Comment: Also, I'm not too sure about the side-note. Carothers' Real Analysis, Pg. $80$ says otherwise. It seems to demand that $A,B$ are disjoint in $M$, i.e. $A\cap B = \varnothing$. Are you sure?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine yes, closed **in $E$** not in $M$, mind you.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine The sidenote is needed in some general spaces, but I think that book works with metric spaces only and then it’s OK.

Answer (score 1):

$E \backslash A$ is closed IN $E$ under the subspace topology since $E \backslash A = A^c \cap E$. Similarly with $B$. In particular, the same idea works for $E \subseteq M$, you just have to be careful with the subspace topology.

Another very useful definition for disconnectedness goes as follows: $X$ is disconnected if there exists a nonempty, proper subset of $X$ that is both open and closed.

Answer (score 1):

$E\subset M$ is disconnected if there exist two non empty sets $A,B$ such that $A\cap \bar B$ and $\bar A\cap B$ are empty such that $E=A\cup B$. Here, $\bar X =X\cup X'$, where $X'$ is the set of all limit points of $X$.

If $A$ and $B$ are closed, then $A'\subseteq A, B'\subseteq B $, so your definition follows from here.